# Highchart formatter function executed twice every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, formatter

I have created a high chart but its formatter function executed twice.

```
formatter: function() {
    console.log("start");
    return this.value;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhx6ebrb/)

Comment: you didn't add the formatter in the fiddle?

Comment: Do you mean that axis.labels.formatter is run twice like here: http://jsfiddle.net/5q47ym4p/ ?

Comment: ya same. jsfiddle.net/5q47ym4p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I have used the older version of [highchart](http://code.highcharts.com/3/highcharts.js)

i have updated to the latest solve the problem.

Thanks Rion and Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation for the `formatter()` function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter), it looks like it is a callback function that is triggered whenever a tooltip is going to be displayed.

So every time that hover over an element, the `formatter()` function will be called to generate the appropriate tooltip for that point as seen by the bevy of alerts in [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhx6ebrb/2/) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Its not a tooltip formatter its a xAxix  formatter.  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: I didn't see the formatter defined within your example fiddle. Can you add it? I would assume that they each function similarly (i.e. when you activate the contents of it to be displayed via the function).